# Only allow write access on property to Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there any way to only allow Entity Framework classes to write/read the `EmailJson` property ? The code works without this but it would be much cleaner if this property could not be altered by any code since having invalid json in it would throw an exception.

I cannot use a backing property because of the generic requirement.

```
public class EmailEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string EmailJson { get; set; }

    public T GetEmail<T>() where T : BaseEmailModel
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(EmailJson);
    }

    public void  GetEmail<T>(T emailModel) where T : BaseEmailModel
    {
        EmailJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a seperate data access tier (for example a class 'EmailEntityService') that is responsible for all access to EmailEntity. All code throughout your solution should only use this service then. If you move EmailEntity to a seperate project you can ensure that access to it is only possible via EmailEntityService (if you keep that service in a project holding a reference to the 'entity project').

So at the end you have (at least) three projects:

1: Entity project

2: Entity services project (with a reference to 1, this project ensures entities cannot be altered directly)

3: Business logic project (with a reference to 2 but not to 1 to prevent direct access to entities)

Since entity classes are just POCOs I don't see any other possibilities to do this on a more technical/basic way.

Comment: So I hide my Entity behind a Dao and I use different assemblies to restrict access to the entity ? Far more complex than what I was hoping for but it'll work and I guess there is no other way to do this? Thank you :-)

Comment: I guess it sounds more complex than it is - this work will not take more than 10 minutes. If you've done it some times multi-tier architectures will become natural for you to code. Besides your problem you will notice other advantages from that (separation of concerns, easier integration with team-based development, testing, facilitation of the exchange of components, etc.).